# How can I extract integers from a string?

Tags: c++, string, text

Consider a string of the form

"number of columns = 5
number of rows = 345
1 3 -5 2 9
4 -10 34 -22 7"

[There are 343 more rows followed by this. However, I guess it will be enough to explain the problem.]

I wish to extract the values `5` and `345` as integers. The substrings "number of columns = " and "number of rows = " are known but the number of digits in the values followed by these strings is not known. However, it is known that the corresponding line ends after the value. I can get to the beginning of the number using the following code

```
std::string searchString = "clause length = ";
int searchStringLength = searchString.length();
std::size_t startAt = result.find(searchString) + searchStringLength;
```

However, I don't know how to detect the end of a line, using which I can extract the values.

And the next part is to extract the rest of the integers and store them in an array and I think if I can identify the positions of the empty spaces and the end of lines, this problem will also get resolved.

How can I solve this problem efficiently [I am using Visual Studio 2017]?

Comment: Hint: Read the contents of the file line by line. Process each line independently.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the following simple number extractor based on regex

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>
#include <string>
#include <regex>

int main()
{
    std::string s = "number of columns = 5\n"
        "number of rows = 345\n"
        "1 3 -5 2 9\n"
        "4 -10 34 -22 7\n";

    std::regex num_regex("\\d+|-\\d+");
    auto num_begin = 
        std::sregex_iterator(s.begin(), s.end(), num_regex);
    auto num_end = std::sregex_iterator();

    for (std::sregex_iterator i = num_begin; i != num_end; ++i) {
        std::smatch match = *i;
        std::string match_str = match.str();
        std::cout << "  " << match_str << '\n';
    }

}
```

Output

```
  5
  345
  1
  3
  -5
  2
  9
  4
  -10
  34
  -22
  7
```

Comment: Wow, 2 upvotes. Good. Did you know that you can replace most of your lines with ````std::copy(std::sregex_token_iterator(s.begin(), s.end(), re, 0), {}, std::ostream_iterator<std::string>(std::cout, "\n"));```` . Or, if you want to put the complete result into a vector, then ````std::vector n(std::sregex_token_iterator(s.begin(), s.end(), re, 0), {});````

Comment: Or, if you want the rows and columns, then ````auto i = std::sregex_token_iterator(s.begin(), s.end(), re, 0);
 long columns = std::stol(*i++);
 long rows = std::stol(*i);````

Comment: @ArminMontigny clarity vs brevity, depends on your audience.

Answer (score 0):

You can split the string into tokens. In this case split the string according to "=" sign and then try to convert them into integer's 
http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strtok/    Go through this link